# Let $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R-\{3\}$ be a function such that there exist $T>0$ with $f(x+T)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R-\{3\}$ be a function with the property that there exist $T>0$ such that $f(x+T)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$. Prove that $f(x)$ is periodic and find the period of $f(x)$.

For $f(x)$ to be periodic, we need to prove $f(x+\lambda)=f(x)$, where $\lambda$ is the fundamental period of $f(x)$. But there seems no path to prove this in the given definition of the function. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I seem to have found something
$$ f(x)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3} $$
replace $ x \rightarrow x+T $ to get
$$
f(x+2T)=\frac{2f(x)-5}{f(x)-2}
$$
now once again replace $ x \rightarrow x+2T $ to get
$$ f(x+4T)=f(x)$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Find expressions of the form $f(x+kT)=\frac{a_kx+b_k}{c_kx+d_k}$, for $k=0$ (trivial), $k=1$ (given), $k=2$, $k=3$, and so on. You'll be surprised (soon enough).

Comment: ,i did not get it Sir,it may be easy but not clicking me.I tried your suggestions on paper.

Comment: Yeah! but why $f(x+kT)=\frac{a_k x+b_k}{c_k x+d_k}$ we know that $f(x+T)=\frac{f(x)-5}{f(x)-3}$ so shouldn't there be $f(x)$ instead of $x$??